# Angular js factory

Tags: angularjs

Не понимаю для чего нужны фабрики в Ангуляр и как они работают, может кто нибудь на пальцах объяснить.(на конкретном легком примере)

Comment: эм, а справку читали?

Comment: да читали, все равно не понимание есть

Comment: точнее не есть непонимание, а нету понимания

Comment: в двух словах: `factory` - это функция которая что-то возвращает, и это значение можно подключать в качестве зависимостей

Comment: Для чего она нужна?

Comment: Хранить какие то данные в ней или что?

Comment: можно простой пример

Comment: да, можно хранить данные, можно использовать в качестве хранилища функций, это просто средство сделать часть кода доступной всему приложению

Comment: [_Вы можете использовать сервисы для организации и совместного использования кода внутри приложения._](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Comment: Фабрика это сервис, который может вернуть любой тип данных. Она не содержит правил по созданию этих данных. Нужно всего лишь вернуть что-то. [Понимание типов сервисов в AngularJS (constant, value, factory, service, provider)](https://habrahabr.ru/post/190342/)